# postgresql database not replicating. No errors

Tags: linux, postgresql, database-replication

**Background:**

I am trying to set up streaming replication between two servers.  Although postgresql is running on both boxes without any errors, when I add or change a record from the primary, these changes are not reflected on the secondary server.

I have the following set up on my primary database server:

(Note:  I'm using fake ip addresses but 10.222.22.12 represents the primary server and .21 the secondary)

**primary server - posgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '10.222.22.12'
unix_socket_directory = '/tmp/postgresql'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 5             # max number of walsender processes
                                # (change requires restart)
wal_keep_segments = 32          # in logfile segments, 16MB each; 0 disables
```

**primary server - pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all             all             10.222.22.21/32         trust
host    replication     postgres        10.222.22.0/32          trust
```

**primary server - firewall**

I've checked to make sure all incoming to the fw is open and that all traffic out is allowed.

**secondary server - posgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '10.222.22.21'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 5             # max number of walsender processes
                                # (change requires restart)
wal_keep_segments = 32          # in logfile segments, 16MB each; 0 disables
hot_standby = on
```

**secondary server - pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all             all             10.222.22.12/32         trust
host    all             all             10.222.22.21/32         trust
host    replication     postgres        10.222.22.0/24          trust
```

**secondary server - recovery.conf**

```
standby_mode='on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.222.22.12 port=5432 user=postgres'
```

**secondary server firewall**

everything is open here too.

**What I've tried so far**

1. Made a change in data on the primary.  Nothing replicated over.
2. Checked the firewall settings on both servers.
3. Checked the arp table on the secondary box to make sure it can communicate with the primary.
4. checked the postmaster.log file on both servers.  They are empty.
5. Checked the syslog file on both servers.  no errors noticed.
6. restarted postgresql on both servers to make sure it starts without errors.

I'm not sure what else to check.  If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT 1**

I've checked the pg_stat_replication table **on the master** and I get the following results:

```
psql -U postgres testdb -h 10.222.22.12 -c "select * from pg_stat_replication;"

 pid | usesysid | usename | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port | backend_start | state | sent_location | write_location | flush_location | repl
ay_location | sync_priority | sync_state 
-----+----------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-----
------------+---------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

And **on the slave**, notice the results from the following query:

```
testdb=# select now()-pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();
 ?column? 
----------

(1 row)
```

openser=#

Comment: Where you able to resolve this @dot? I'm facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the pg_hba.conf file on the primary and added the exact ip addr of my slave like so:

```
host    all             all             10.222.22.21/32         trust
host    replication     postgres        10.222.22.0/32          trust
#added the line below
host    replication     postgres        10.222.22.12/32         trust
```

Then I restarted postgresql and it worked. 
I guess I was expecting that the line above the new line I added would work, but it's not. I have to do more reading on subnetting.

Comment: If you want to allow 10.222.22.X, you need to use 10.222.22.0/24 (that's the 24 starting bits in the IP-address as network mask). What you have is that EXACTLY the address 10.222.22.0 need to match (32 bits, which means the complete IP address).

Comment: +1 @jishi.  Thanks for the explanation. I plan to do more research on subnets but in the mean time, this explanation is great.

Answer (score 0):

On master, listen address should allow connection from slave, i.e

```
listen_addresses = '10.222.22.21'
```

It seems your postgres logging not well configured.

My guess is, the slave cannot stream because it falls behind the master, it can be due to network latency.

My suggestion is, You should archive the wal files, so if the slave falls behind the master, it can replay wal files from the archive.

You can also check by doing

```
select * from pg_stat_replication;
```

on master. If it does not show any rows, it means that streaming fails, probably due to slave falls behind the master.

You can also check by issuing :

```
select now()-pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();
```

on slave. The query count how far the slave falls behind the master.

Usually, streaming replication lag is under 1s. Lag larger than 1s, then streaming will be cut off.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!  I do believe the listen_address setting I have on the primary is correct.  I actually have two instances of postgresql running for separate databases on the primary server.  There a db on localhost (127.0.0.1) and another database on 10.222.22.12.  This second instance is what's being replicated over to a slave server.

Comment: How can I prove that it's an issue with network latency?  Please see Edit 1 in my post for results of the queries you've suggested I run.

Comment: It seems you didn't configured streaming replication well. To make sure, please check this query on streaming replication slave : select pg_is_in_recovery();
a well configured streaming replication slave will return true.
others will return false.
You can also check : select pg_is_xlog_replay_paused();
more details on : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html
btw, what is your PG version?